# Is there any way to check if a class is abstract?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I need a way to check if a class is abstract. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Mirrors should probably offer this information, but it doesn't appear to. All I can think of is to try to instantiate the class and catch the exception, but this means you have to statically know the constructor signature.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to port a Java code snippet where a check was made ​​if a class was abstract or not, and on this basis created an instance of that using reflection. Reviewing the code now, I see no need to do this check. I can simply instantiate and check if any error occurs. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the answer right now is: you can't.

As Justin mentioned, there is a [Mirrors API](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_mirrors.html) for reflection capabilities. However, there doesn't seem to be a flag for "is abstract".

If this is functionality that you'd like to see, you can file a feature request here: http://dartbug.com/new

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```dart
library x;

import 'dart:mirrors';

abstract class MyAbstract {
  void doSomething();
}

class MyConcrete{
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  print('MyAbstract: ${isAbstract(MyAbstract)}');
  print('MyConcrete: ${isAbstract(MyConcrete)}');
}

bool isAbstract(Type t) {
  ClassMirror cm = reflectClass(t);
  if(cm.declarations.values.firstWhere(
      (MethodMirror mm) => mm.isAbstract == true, orElse: () => null) != null) {
    return true;
  }
  try {
    InstanceMirror i = cm.newInstance(new Symbol(''), []);
  } catch(e) {
    return (e is AbstractClassInstantiationError);
  }
  return false;
}
```

the `newInstance` part should be extended to check if there isn't a default constructor and try named constructors instead.

AFAIR there was [a discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/topic/misc/sBOGTD5btaM/discussion) recently if it should be allowed to instantiate an abstract class (in relation to dependency injection) if this changes above method might not work anymore but I couln't find something about it in the issue tracker.

Also star this feature request: [Add a method to check if a class is abstract](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12826)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible via [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming).

In furtherance of the discussion that had occurred here on the missing functionality, the required "isAbstract" feature was committed after about a year on Jan 9, 2014 (as visible from the [history at GitHub](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/commit/7dfcd0f4a1c5604189f04b5e3df53b35a50266ed)).

The [`dart:mirrors`](https://api.dart.dev/dev/2.0.0-dev.40.0/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html) library makes it achievable quite easily:

##### Dart SDK

- `dart:mirrors`

  - `ClassMirror`

    - `isAbstract`

## Demo

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class ConcreteClass {}

abstract class AbstractClass {}

void main() {
  ClassMirror mirroredClass;

  mirroredClass = reflectClass(ConcreteClass);
  print(mirroredClass.isAbstract); // false

  mirroredClass = reflectClass(AbstractClass);
  print(mirroredClass.isAbstract); // true
}
```

**Documentation:** https://api.dart.dev/dev/2.0.0-dev.40.0/dart-mirrors/ClassMirror/isAbstract.html